# When is CollectionView.Refresh() usually required?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I am not familiar at all with using WPF and the application that I am working on had a `ListCollectionView.Refresh()` every time one of the objects in the ListCollection View Model would change which made the application extremely inefficient (`ListCollectionView` is binded to List Collection View Model). After removing the `Refresh()` the application runs a lot smoother and still updates when changes occur in ListCollection View Model. After looking around it seems that any time there is a filter or re-sort on the `CollectionView` there is an implicit call to `Refresh()`. So when is it necessary to `Refresh()` and recreate the `CollectionView`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you have a `ListCollectionView` that is bound to a ListCollectionViewModel (your own class). As long as ListCollectionViewModel implements `INotifyCollectionChanged` properly (eg. it inherits from ObservableCollection<T>), and the items in the collection implement `INotifyPropertyChange` properly, then it is not necessary to call Refresh().

Answer (score 0):

CollectionView doesn't handle CollectionChanged events where more than one item is changing (an exception occurs); `Refresh()` can be used instead, which is why you are seeing calls with filters and sorts.